# Android Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps

Is this possible in Android, when i will say a name of place google map pointer will zoom to that place. i.e. I want to search Map by voice
if possible then how to do this? Though i have done so many apps in Google map, but din't try this before! Can any body help?

Answer (score 3):

[this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) should be useful to start off.then you can go through these [APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html).If you want to include the voice recoginition part , now APIs are available from level 8.check this out. [RecognizerIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html).you can even use the Voice recoginition [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [animateTo](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html) method of the `MapController` class.  I think this will do what you're looking for.

Comment: i want when i will say vocally name of place, map will zoom to that place

Comment: ok..so you are looking for artificial intelligence voice recoginition?

Comment: @smsys.. I have included the voice recoginition Apis in the answer..use 2.3 version!!